# changing the asp:Image ImageUrl attribute Depending on Condition in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, resx, asp.net-controls

i'm building a simple reporting applications , in which user has notifications i want to check if the notification is unRead  i'll display a read image icon 
and if it was read , i'll display Read Icon

ive created a **TicketIsUnRead()** function to check if the ticket was read|unread

and i've used this code in **aspx page** that attaches different resource to the asp:image control  different resources are responsible for changing the **ImageUrl** attribute

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="ticketIcon"  meta:resourcekey='<% (TicketIsUnRead(ticketNumberField.ToString()))? "UnReadticketIconResource" :"ReadticketIconResource"%>' />
```

and inside the **Resx page**

```
UnReadticketIconResource.ImageUrl           images/UnReadMail.png
ReadticketIconResource.ImageUrl         images/ReadMail.png
```

it seems  that the Meta:resourcekey attribute doesn't allow  the  <% %> code

it returns parse error exception

```
Parser Error Message: '<% (TicketIsUnRead(ticketNumberField.ToString()))? "UnReadticketIconResource" :"ReadticketIconResource"%>' is not a valid resource key.
```